# C# comparing Date & Time in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Using linq, i want to return only those records whose date & time is greater than the provided date. The record has date and time in different columns in string formats.
For e.g., "290811" for (29/Aug/2011) and "1400" for (2 PM or 14 hours depending on the context it's being used).

What i have done:

```
var result = from s in source
             where GetDateTime(s.date, s.time) >= myDateTime
             select s;
```

`GetDateTime` is a function i've created to return the date and time in DateTime format.
`myDatetime` is the date i'm passing.

**Edit:** Functions Used:

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(string strDate, string strTime) {
    DateTime dt;
    int dd = Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Substring(0, 2));
    int mm = Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Substring(2, 2));
    int yy = Convert.ToInt32("20" + strDate.Substring(4, 2));

    TimeSpan ts = GetTimeFromString(strTime);

    dt = new DateTime(yy, mm, dd, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, 0);            

    return dt;
}

public static TimeSpan GetTimeFromString(string strTime) {
    int hh = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Substring(0, 2));
    int mins = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Substring(2, 2));        
    return new TimeSpan(hh, mins, 0);
}
```

Sample Data:

```
Adt_avlStatus   7
Adt_BaseFare    100
Adt_breakPoint  Y
Adt_cabin       M
Adt_Discount    0
Adt_Farebasis   EAP14DN
Adt_fareType    RP
Adt_Markup      0
Adt_rbd     E
date        290811
time        1520
Origin      IXC
Destination     GOI
```

`myDateTime` sample: `20/08/2011 17:35:00` (20/Aug/2011 5:35 PM)

The problem is that the above linq is not filtering the results as it should. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the implementation of `GetDateTime()`.

Comment: How do you want to help you without knowing what do you do?

Comment: `GetDateTime` function added.

Comment: Is source an IQueryable coming from a database? If so, I suspect the problem is that the provider cannot convert "GetDateTime(...)" to SQL. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Galloway, no error, it's returning all the results without filtration. Source is a list of an object.

Comment: @jSang: The code looks ok - provide sample data, please.

Comment: And some sample data for `myDateTime`, too, please

Answer (score 1):

I assume, `myDateTime` also contains a time part. If I understood you correctly, you want `myDateTime` to only contain a date part. You can verify this:
`myDateTime` contains a time part, if `myDateTime != myDateTime.Date`.

Comment: yes `myDateTime` contains time as well. Also, i want to compare using both date and time.

Comment: Yes, time is important for comparison purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what is visible in your question, the bug is GetDateTime, s.date or s.time. Are you sure GetDateTime is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, i've debugged my code and `GetDateTime` is returning the date and time in DateTime format as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not filter the results as it should, your `GetDateTime()` method must be flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Without the data we can still only speculate.

The problem is either:

- an incorrect value coming back from `GetDateTime` because the input data from `source` was not in the format you expect
- the value of `myDateTime` is either not set or set too low, which means all dates in your incoming data are greater than it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var result = from s in source let dt = GetDateTime(s.date, s.time)
             where dt >= myDateTime
             select s;
```